# Asus Table T100HA webcam does not work with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: asus, webcam, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Asus Table T100HA and the Webcam no longer works. I tried with Cheese and some other Programs on my Browser...

I need some Help. - Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a permissions issue, try `sudo chmod 777 /dev/video`.

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 /dev/video*`

Comment: Thanks - I got the exact same error message except with the asterisk included /dev/video*

Comment: No idea why. An option is to lower the resolution from "Preferences" in Cheese and restart it until you get it working, but this is a workaround and not a clear answer to your question.

Comment: Because it does not recognize a webcam, it does not give me an option to lower the resolution in Cheese.

Comment: @KevinB how did you made the sound to work on Ubuntu 20.04? My t100HAN doesn't work the sound at all!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a desktop machine with a USB webcam. After 20.04 upgrade there's no webcam shown with `lsusb` and no files seen at `/dev/video`.

I fixed it by uninstalling Cheese:

```
sudo apt-get remove cheese
```

I installed guvcview:

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
```

Then unplugged and replugged the USB webcam and ran  `guvcview`.

Files have now appeared at `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`. The webcam appears when I run `lsusb` and is functioning in Google Meet and Zoom.

Comment: I have also used external USB Webcams and have had no problems with them. (Logitech). This specific thread was about my embedded webcam in the ASUS Laptop. I believe that the problem is caused by a lack of Drivers in the distro of Linux. I have since installed Mint/Linux and the embedded webcam does not work there either. I am not alone, as there are scads of posts with users with the same problem. So, the solution is to buy a popular external webcam like a Logitech, and it will probably be recognized.

Comment: OK, but my webcam is an external Logitech USB, and it was working fine until I upgraded Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 So I think the problem was with the upgrade package.

Comment: I have big issues with my Logitech Brio 4K on 20.04. I works from time to time, but mostly it just shows a black screen.
I've also tried the apt version of cheese and also guvcview, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the snap package. It Is borked, like many snap packages.

Install the normal version:

```
sudo apt install cheese
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the dmesg and found that the bitrate did not match. I attached the webcam to a USB 2.0 port and now it works perfectly.

At least it resolved the issue for me.